# Send a message if the channel already exists

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a kind of ticket system. Suppose someone has a ticket open called `ticket-$ {message.author.username}` how can I prevent that person from making another ticket? Because the way I try it doesn't work.

Edit: I've added a lot more code now, this is almost my whole code. I still get an error with these changes.

Code:

```
   module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    message.delete();

    const filter = (reaction, user) => ['️', '‍', '️', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

    var name = `ticket-${message.author.username}`
    const category = message.guild.channels.cache.get('708800011160256582');
    let supportRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("708629895621640242");
    let supportRole2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("708628839659733032");
    let chan = `ticket-${message.author.username}`;

    if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === chan)) {
        return message.channel.send("TEST")
    } else {

        message.guild.channels.create(name, {
            parent: category,
            topic: ` TICKET | ${message.author.username}`,
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: message.author.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
            }, {
                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],

            }, {
                id: supportRole,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],

            }, {
                id: supportRole2,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']

            }]
        })
    }
      }).then(async c => {

        let orderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Choose one of the topics below.")
            .setColor("#e05856")
            .setDescription(`
            ️ » **Make order.**
            ‍ » **Personal support.**
            ️ » **Technical support (Personal)**
             » **Something else.**
            `)
            .setTimestamp();


            c.send(orderEmbed).then(async msg => {

                await msg.react("️");
                await msg.react("‍");
                await msg.react('️');
                await msg.react("");

                msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 30000,
                    errors: ['time']
                }).then(collected => {

                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    switch(reaction.emoji.name) {
                        case '️':
                             c.send("test1");
                            break;
                        case '‍':
                            c.send("test2");
                            break;
                        case '️':
                            c.send("test3");
                             break;
                        case '':
                            c.send("test4");
                            break;
                    }

                }).catch(collected => {

                });

            })


      });

    message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author.username}! You have opened an order, view it in #${name.id}`).then(async msg => {


    })

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "order"
}
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? specifically, the part where you create a channel

Comment: on your find method, why are you comparing the name of the channel with the ticket?

Comment: Done @Syntle, i have edited my message

Comment: What do you mean? @DjellalMohamedAniss

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but since you said it's not working, do this:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  message.delete();

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['️', '‍', '️', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

  var name = `ticket-${message.author.username}`
  const category = message.guild.channels.cache.get('708800011160256582');
  let supportRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("708629895621640242");
  let supportRole2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("708628839659733032");
  let chan = `ticket-${message.author.username}`;

  if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === chan)) {
    return message.channel.send("TEST")
  } else {

    message.guild.channels.create(name, {
        parent: category,
        topic: ` TICKET | ${message.author.username}`,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
        }, {
          id: message.guild.id,
          deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],

        }, {
          id: supportRole,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],

        }, {
          id: supportRole2,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']

        }]
      })
      .then(async c => {

        let orderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("Choose one of the topics below.")
          .setColor("#e05856")
          .setDescription(`
            ️ » **Make order.**
            ‍ » **Personal support.**
            ️ » **Technical support (Personal)**
             » **Something else.**
            `)
          .setTimestamp();


        c.send(orderEmbed).then(async msg => {

          await msg.react("️");
          await msg.react("‍");
          await msg.react('️');
          await msg.react("");

          msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
          }).then(collected => {

            const reaction = collected.first();

            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
              case '️':
                c.send("test1");
                break;
              case '‍':
                c.send("test2");
                break;
              case '️':
                c.send("test3");
                break;
              case '':
                c.send("test4");
                break;
            }

          }).catch(collected => {

          });

        })


      });

    message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author.username}! You have opened an order, view it in #${name.id}`).then(async msg => {


    })

  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "order"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I can still create a ticket even though I already have some open.

Comment: I fixed the answer

Comment: I've added a lot more code now, this is almost my whole code. I still get an error with these changes.

Comment: I fixed the answer, your problem was caused because you closed the `if/else` statement before your `.then()` you're supposed to contain it all in that else statement's brackets

Comment: It still makes a ticket... hmm

Comment: I think I know why. If I change the name of the ticket to "ticket" instead of "`ticket-${message.author.username}`" it will work. How do I fix this?

Comment: But I would like to put `${message.author.username}` in the ticket name

Comment: Do you have a solution? @Syntle